# TableView rows not updating after core data insert

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm very new to swift programming. I have been playing around with this for a while, but I am not getting anywhere so asking here.

I have a tableview which I can load the data into the view from CoreData no problem. I have an ADD button at the top that segue's to a new tableview, with a long list of options they can pick from.  This tableview also works fine, and includes a search bar.
When the user selects an item row from the second tableview, it inserts that item into CoreData and segue's back to the first tableview.  This is where my problem is, the data does NOT update on the visible view.

I call tableview.reloaddata() and I can see my code calling the fetchedResultsController with the new query that would return with the new data.  But the code never gets to the cellForRowAtIndexPath func so therefore the visible data view never changes. It remains the same display that was visible when the add button was pressed.

How does the visible data get updated? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, if you want it to "automatically" update the contents of the tableview then there are a couple of things you need to make sure of...

1. You have to become the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implements the methods necessary for the updating of the table view. These are quite lengthy and can be found on the [Ray Wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller). The code on here is in Objective-C but it's fairly easy to convert to Swift.
2. The second thing you need is to make sure that the core data update is done on a background thread. Again the website linked above shows this.

Once you've done that then you don't actually need to run `[tableview reloadData]` because the fetched results controller methods will manage everything for you.

Comment: Fogmeister, thanks so much for your pointers in the above.  They helped pointed me at the fundamental issue to help me solve my lack of understanding on this issue.  It was actually a problem with how I was dealing with the FetchedResultsController.